# Angular html5 mode and HAL browser

Tags: java, angularjs, regex, spring, spring-boot

I'm implementing the html5 mode in an AngularJS application. In the server I need to forward everything without a suffix (so without extension,  not a static resource) to the base url:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

This is working fine for the Angular app, but now people want to use the HAL browser and this controller is forwarding also some of the browser requests, like https://localhost:8080/api.

Is it possible to modify the regular expression to match everything without a suffix (as it is now), and everything without  /api?

This is the current regular expression:

```
"/{path:[^\\.]*}"
```

For example:

It should not match:

- anything/api
- anything/apianything
- anything/filename.extension
- anything/filename.extensionanything

(the last two points in the list are ok with the current regex)

It should match:

- everything not listed above

Comment: Try `"/{path:^(?!https?://.*/[^/]+)[^.]*}"`

Comment: But why the https? it should match everything without extension and everything without api. I will edit to add a list of examples

Comment: Ok, try `"/{path:^(?!(?:.*[^/]/)?api)[^.]*$}"`

Comment: You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/wE7eN6/1).

Comment: At the end it worked like this: "/{path:(?!(?:.*)?api)[^.]*}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may use

```
"/{path:(?!.*api)[^.]*}"
```

It matches a string that has no dots and no `api` substring anywhere on the line. Note that in case you have a multiline input, use `[\s\S]` instead of the `.` inside the lookahead. The pattern also allows an empty string (replace final `*` with +` if empty input is not allowed).

Also, mind that in case the pattern is not anchored by default (I think it is here) or you want to test it at regex testers, you need to add anchors: `"/{path:^(?!.*api)[^.]*$}"`. The `^` anchor matches the start of the string and `$` anchor matches the end of the string.

Comment: It seems to work. One last question, how would it be if i wanted to match a string that has no dots,  and no api substring at the beggining of the line (api not anywhere but not only at the beggining)

Comment: To match a pattern at the beginning of the line, you need `^` anchor or a `(?m)^` or a `(^|\n)`. So you need something like  `(^|\n)(?!api)[^.]*$`